# Create a ee.FeatureCollection out of a .tif file

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff

I am using the Earth Engine API in a Python Jupyter notebook.

I have several .tif files in my local folder and I would like to create ee objects (FeatureCollection a priori) to manipulate them. Is possible without adding them in my assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible without adding them in my assets?

No. To work with images in Earth Engine, they must always be uploaded first.

However, you can use Python to upload them all into one collection — you will have just the collection in your asset list.

1. Create the collection.
2. Use `os.listdir` in Python to find the file names (or write them in by hand, whatever works for you).
3. In a loop, upload each one with `ee.data.startIngestion`, giving it **an asset ID like `users/myusername/my_collection/image`** where `my_collection` is the ID of the collection you already created.

Comment: I'm sad but thank you (the idea was to limit the request to the server) I'll work with gdal instead