# Uploading images to GEE with the Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

I have some images on a Google Cloud Storage bucket that I need to upload to GEE for processing. This is easily accomplished using the ["earthengine" command line tool](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#upload), but I would like to do the same on Colab, using the Python API.
So far I've found on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367966/181753) that it could be accomplished with `ee.data.startIngestion()`, but that answer and also the [documentation](https://gee-python-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ee.html#ee.data.startIngestion) are not clear (at least to me) on how to populate its parameters.

This is what I have using the earthengine command line tool as a subprocess:

```py
import ee
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import check_output
from google.colab import auth

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
auth.authenticate_user()

storage_client = storage.Client(project=<project name>)
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(<bucket name>)

for blob in blobs:
    info=check_output(["earthengine","upload","image",<bucket name>+blob.name,"--asset_id=<user name and folder>"+blob.name.split(".")[0]])
    print(info)
```

This does the job, but I would like to know how to use `ee.data.startIngestion()` since it's part of the Python API. This should replace the subprocess `check_output()`.

Could anyone provide an example on how to use it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree the documentation is not very clear, had to look at the earthengine code directly for this one.

```py
asset_id = "<username/folder>"
gcloud_uri = "<gs://bucket/blob>"

request_id = ee.data.newTaskId()[0]
params = {
    "name": f"projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/{asset_id}",
    "tilesets": [{"sources": [{"uris": [gcloud_uri]}]}]
}
ee.data.startIngestion(request_id=request_id, params=params)
```

Should do the same thing as:

```
earthengine upload image --asset_id <asset_id> <gcloud_uri>
```